# Cucumber runtime exception when my feature file contains Korean characters

Tags: java, cucumber-jvm

I have looked everywhere on the web to see if anyone posted a similar issue but not been so lucky. I am running automation tests scripts using Java with Cucumber JVM. I have a step that involves verifying a Korean character but when I try to run it, i get a cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Error parsing feature file

Does anyone have a suggestion about this? It's imperative i use that character as part of my input as it's verifying a site based in Korea.

Hope that is clear enough.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show you feature file

Comment: Are you using UTF-8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `# language: ko` in your feature file (the very first line)